# Find all irreducible representations $\pi$ of G and matrices $\pi$(x) and $\pi$(y) with respect to suitable basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Here is the information I have:

- G is the group of order 21
- it is generated by two elements $x$ and $y$
- $x^7=y^3=e$
- $xy=yx^2$

I want to do two things:

1. Construct all irreducible representations of G
2. Write down, for each $\pi$  the matrices $\pi$(x) and $\pi$(y) (with respect to suitable basis)

---

My idea:
First find the 1-dimensional relresentations and consider dimensions of the others but I am finding it very difficult to make progess on this.

Comment: Do you want complex representations? Have you been able to determine the number of irreducible representations and their degrees?

Comment: @ahulpke thanks for the reply. How would i determine the number of irreducible representations? Is it calculated using the group order? Also , I think real representations is what I am dealing with

Comment: To give you a plausible answer it would be helpful to get a brief idea of "where you are" mathematically. E.g., this question could be typical for a graduate student taking a class on representation theory, but if you are for example a physicist with a concrete calculation problem you will want another answer.

Comment: @ahulpke I am a third year mathematics student, doing a course in representation theory; I am also finding it my most difficult class

Answer (score 3):

Initially looking at this over the complex numbers is easier. A few fundamental theorems (which I suppose you have seen in your class) are:

- The number of representations is the number of conjugacy classes.
- The sum of the degrees squared is the group order and the degrees divide the group order
- The number of 1-dimensional representations is the index of the derived subgroup.
- Permutation representations are induced trivial representations.

With this the following approach (not all details are spelled out) will get you the representations:

Your group has (explicit calculations....) 5 conjugacy classes (with representatives $1,x,y,x^3,y^2$) and derived subgroup (generated by $x$) of order 7. So there are 5 irreducible representations, of degrees $1,1,1,3,3$.

The 1-domensional representations simply need to map $x$ trivially and $y$ to a 3-rd root of unity.

To get the other ones, note that the group has a faithful transitive permutation representation (on the cosets of $<y>$) of degree 7: $x\mapsto (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$, $y\mapsto (2,3,5)(4,7,6)$. The point stabilizer has 3 orbits, so it is the sum of 3 irreducible representations, one of which is the trivial one.

The trivial representation is on the submodule spanned by $(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$. The quotient module (for the permutation module) gives you a 6-dimensional real representation that is the sum of two complex conjugate 3-dimensional ones. If you only want real representations you are done. If you want complex 3-dimensional representations I would try to induce up a nontrivial 1-dimensional representation of $<x>$.